# Создать цикл на Python для подсчета сложного процента с налоговым отчислением по ИИС

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Условие задачи:**

1. Ежегодный вклад - 400,000₽
2. Дивиденды по акциям = 10% годовых
3. Налоговый вычет 13%.

Необходимо подсчитать сложный процент за 20 лет вклада.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: подсчитайте раз необходимо

Comment: "Налоговый вычет 13%" а из чего вычет то? В задаче никакие налоги не упоминаются, из чего вычет вычитать то? Ну и в целом да: решайте задачу, будут сложности - задавайте вопросы. После попыток решения, а не до.

Comment: @CrazyElf
Ежегодный вклад 400,000 руб/год, налоговый вычет с каждого вклада (400,000 руб) 13 % = 400,000 + (400,000 х 0.13) = 452,000 руб. В итоге мы получаем, что ежегодный вклад в акции по 10% годовых составляет 452,000 руб и тут нужно подсчитать сложный процент. Но мне нужен цикл на Python

Comment: А, я понял. Просто вы неправильно используете термин "налоговый вычет". "Налог" - это то, что забирают у вас. А "налоговый вычет" - это когда наоборот вам возвращают часть уплаченных ранее налогов. Путаница в терминах.

Answer (score 2):

```
deposit_amount = 400000         # начальный депозит
deposit_amount_cumsum = 400000  # нарощенный депозит, изначально равен стартовой сумме
replenishment_period = 1        # период пополнения
time_deposit = 20               # время инвестирования в годах
dividend_percent = 0.1          # дивидендный процент - 10% от суммы депозита, то есть 0.1
tax = 0.13                      # налог - 13% от суммы прибыли, то есть 0.13
profit = 0                      # прибыль

for year in range(1, time_deposit + 1):
    revenue = deposit_amount_cumsum * (1 + dividend_percent) - deposit_amount_cumsum
    profit += revenue - revenue * tax
    deposit_amount_cumsum += deposit_amount + profit
    print(f"нарощенная прибыль на {year} год составляет {profit}")
```

А вообще, для таких целей лучше не программирование использовать, есть [онлайн калькуляторы](https://a2-finance.com/ru/calculators/vse/kalkulyator-slozhnyh-procentov?calc_fields%5Binitial_amount%5D=1000&calc_fields%5Bunit%5D=%E2%82%BD&calc_fields%5Bcontribution_amount%5D=400000&calc_fields%5Bfrequency_contributions%5D=1&calc_fields%5Binterest_rate_amount%5D=10&calc_fields%5Bcompounded_intervals%5D=1&calc_fields%5Bnumber_years%5D=2#calc)

Comment: Спасибо Зарина, знаю о существовании данного ресурса, но мне нужен был питоновский цикл